# Find the same value in three Colomns with same name but in different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently making an android app which uses a feed to display statuses made by users. I have three tables within the same database, each has username either as a primary or unique key column, but each table has different information relating to that user.

For instance, the first table ===>> tbl_users:

- username
- fname (first name)
- mname (middle name)
- lname (last name)
- etc. (the list is long)

The second table ===>> tbl_userprofilepictures:

- profilepictureID
- username
- profilepicturepath

The third table ===>> tbl_user_feed:

- postID (the status' unique ID)
- username
- status
- imagepostpath (the path to the image uploaded with the status)
- timestamp

I want to be able to search for the username across all three tables and display the relevant information relating to them on their post. For example I will need their name and surname for tbl_users and I will need their profilepicturepath for tbl_userprofilepictures as well as their status, imagepostpath and timestamp from tbl_user_feed.

Would I need to do this in a seperate PHP file or in the app itself? PS I'm fairly noob at PHP so please feel free to help a bro out.

May the force be with you.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` is the way to go.

Comment: @GordonLinoff hey thanks for the reply, would you be able to explain JOIN a bit more? Like I said, I'm very rookie with regards to PHP :3

Comment: Normalize your Database! This will make it much easier and prevents a lot of problems.

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX this is going to sound bad but firstly what is normalising and secondly, how do I do that? c:

Comment: @Brian Normalizing is one of the most important things when you are working with databases. It prevents anomalies, inconsistency and redundancy and makes it much easier working with your sql-database. Here is a link that will help you: http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization            The first three steps I would recommend. Its very easy and you will see fast that its helpful. Good luck ;)

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX thanks, you've been a massive help! :)

Comment: Also do some google search on sql joins to find more out about this concept as well. If you want to handle databases in your application, then it would be wise to get to know at least the basics **before** using them. Also, if you are new to your chosen programming language in the same time as well, then you may not want to start with a project that handles databases just yet. It would make things a bit less complicated.

Comment: @Shadow I actually have a database analyst on my team (I do the front-end), i do the basic (I mean BASIC) DB operations just so my code can function and he rewrites it all in a more logical manner. But I am definitely going to google that thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN`.

What is `JOIN` ?

> An SQL JOIN clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a common field between them.

Source : [w3schools.com Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Here is the sample I made base on your tables given. For these one our common field is `username`.

```
SELECT CONCAT('a.fname', 'a.lname'), b.profilepictureID, c.status, c.imagepostpath, c.timestamp 
FROM 
tbl_users as a
LEFT JOIN tbl_userprofilepictures as b ON b.username = a.username
LEFT JOIN tbl_user_feed as c ON c.username = a.username
```

Using `Alias (table_name as custom_name)` is a good practice in joining the tables